# DBSCAN plotting Non-geometrical-Data

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I used [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) cluster-algorithm dbscan to get clusters of my data. 
**Data:** Non-Geometrical objects based on hex-decimal strings

I used a simple distance to create a distance matrix as input for dbscan resulting in expected clusters.

**Question** Is it possible to create a plot of these cluster-results like in [demo](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#example-cluster-plot-dbscan-py)

I didn't found a solution through search. 
I need to graphically demonstrate the similarities of the objects and clusters to each other.

Since I am using python for everything (in that project) I would appreciate it to choose a solution in python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use python, so I cannot give you example code.

If your data isn't 2 dimensional, you can try to find a good 2-dimensional approximation using Multidimensional Scaling.

Essentially, it takes an input matrix (which should satistify triangular ineuqality, and ideally be derived from Euclidean distance in some vector space; but you can often get good results if this does not strictly hold). It then tries to find the best 2-dimensional data set that has the same distances.